# How to change 2024.01 to date Jan 2024 in Power BI [Raw data come from Excel]

Tags: powerbi, daxstudio

How to change data 2024.01 to date Jan 2024 in Power BI? [Raw data come from Excel]

For example,

| data | date |
| --- | --- |
| 2024.01 | Jan 2024 |
| 2024.02 | Feb 2024 |

Could you please describe step by step to change this kind of data?

Thank you for your sharing

Comment: PowerQuery is your friend! Right-click on the table, Edit Query, Remove the Changed Type step (if there is one). Right-click the text date column (with the periods as delimiter). Replace the "." with "/". Change the data type to date.

Answer (score 0):

First convert data into date format in Power Query by splitting column, reordering columns, merging columns

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjIwMtEzMFSK1YGxjZRiYwE=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [data = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"data", type number}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"data", type text}}, "en-US"), "data", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(".", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"data.1", "data.2"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"data.1", Int64.Type}, {"data.2", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Changed Type1",{"data.2", "data.1"}),
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Reordered Columns", {{"data.2", type text}, {"data.1", type text}}, "en-US"),{"data.2", "data.1"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("/", QuoteStyle.None),"Date"),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Merged Columns",{{"Date", type date}})
in
    #"Changed Type2"
```

Then write a calculated column to get desired result

```
Column = FORMAT(MONTH('Table'[Date]), "mmm ") & YEAR('Table'[Date])
```